Is is possible to Connect one Master port to multiple Slave ports in GEM5?
I am trying to connect a master port of a ram to slave ports of multiple rams in my Python config file:
system.lvsram0.m0_port.connect(system.lvsram0.s0_ports[0])
system.lvsram0.m0_port.connect(system.lvsram1.s0_ports[0])
... // there are more rams (system.lvsrami)

but I am getting an error saying:
fatal: Port .lvsram0.m0_port is already connected to .lvsram0.s0_ports[0], cannot connect .lvsram1.s0_ports[0]
Is it possible to do this? Or should I use a SystemXbar()?
